# Re-writing static website in angular 6. Will default 404 route hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, 404, iis, soft-404, web.config

Let us say our previous website was a WordPress application with links like `example.com/about-us` that served up static pages.

Well now our application is an Angular 6 SPA being served in IIS through Azure. Right now to solve broken links on search results that have the old site cached we are using the default catch-all angular 404 technique.

```
  {
    path: '404', component: Error404Component
  },
  {
    path: '**', redirectTo: '404'
  }
```

I am worried that since all of these dead links on search results now return a `status 200` instead of a `status 404` that Google and Bing will think these are still valid links and never update them. Even worse is that the IIS `web.config` code to make angular routes work on refresh / direct navigation:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/"/>
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

also prevents 404 codes from being sent back in the http headers since it still served `index.html/root` and its the angular router that crashes.

Is this a valid concern?

Comment: Can you redirect all the old URLs to their new counterparts?

Comment: Not all of them have counterparts.

Comment: Usually rewrite maps can be used, to map important old links to new links, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module, and 301 redirection would force Google/Bing to update their indexed items to the new links. You only need this in the first few weeks and just a few rules on the most frequently visited pages.